# .NET 4 Content Based WCF Routing vs. .NET 3.5 Compact Framework

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-4.0

I consider using .NET 4.0 Content Based WCF Routing. Currently I have a normal .NET 3.5 WCF Server. All Clients uses the compact framework .NET 3.5. Could there be a problem, if I will port my WCF Server to .NET 4.0?

Thanks for your answer.

Kind regards, pro

Answer (score 1):

What does one have to do with the other? Content-based routing services inspect SOAP messages based on various possible criteria and select the proper endpoint to forward a request to. The routing service itself is just another WCF service with the standard assortment of WCF protocol and binding types. Receive request on an endpoint, process for given criteria, forward request to another endpoint.

But that said, mobile is pretty volatile and uncertain, and you can never be 100% certain until you test it. This is something you should be able to test in under 30 minutes; maybe even under 10.